# Symfony 2 form names for batch actions?

Tags: symfony

I have a list of items as an html table. I want to have an opportunity to save some data in batch mode. 
To do this I need my form field names looks like this: **provider[i][title]** etc.
But when I try to create form field, i get an error:

form type name ("provider[0]") is not valid. Names must only contain letters, numbers, and "_".

I've red about form collections, but it is not exactly I need.

I want to get whole form in action just as $request->request->get('provider'), and then iterate to get actual data.. 
I'm confused!! It's the simplest task as i can imagine.

```
<input type='text' name='provider[0][title]'>
<input type='text' name='provider[1][title]'>
<input type='text' name='provider[2][title]'>
```

I can use $request->request->all(), it is a solution, but not so elegant I think. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is completely normal that you can't name directly your field with a name like "provider[0]". This part of the field name is generated by Symfony.

For me the only (good) way to store multiples entities in one form is to use collections. They are well explained in Symfony2's documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

In your case you just have to create a form with one collection field and adding row in your controller or on the flight with javascript. For the "provider" field, just create a formType with one text field.

If you work with an html array you can simply add a row for each entity. The i in provider[i] will be bound with entities in database if they are not linked to an other entity.

Finally, using POST data is definitely not a good solution : you will lose form field assertion and CSRF protection.